# Handling events from file menu

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, python-2.7

I am trying to code a program with a regular file menu. (e.g. File, Edit, View, etc).

I want the action they take in that menu to update my status bar (a label).

The problem is, the way I have it setup now, I believe it's executing the command and then trying to take the result as what it should do.

Currently a menu item is defined like so:

```
fileMenu.add_command(label="Insert", command=self.statusUpdater(statusLabel,"Insert   Triggered")
```

And the function statusUpdater is defined as such:

```
 def statusUpdater(self,status,commandName):

    status.config(text=commandName)
    status.update_idletasks()
```

So the problem is, right at the start of the program, the status changes to "Insert Triggered". What I want is for that to only happy once I have actually clicked "Insert"

From hints I've seen elsewhere it seems like I need some way to pass and handle the **event** of Insert being clicked.

Could someone supply a generic and basic function that does what I ask? I think the problem lies in the () attached to the command function, but I don't know any other way to pass arguments.

All i need is a function that is called on the click event, and knows which fileMenu command triggered it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Commands take a reference to a function. You can se a lambda if you want to pass it arguments:

```
...command=lambda l=statusLabel, self.statusUpdater(l, "Insert Triggered"))
```